# new(ish) Sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence, identity

I have an old site that used to use `Identity` to get a new invoice number.

In SQL Server 2005, this worked fine, but since moving to SQL Server 2014, I get gaps (approx 1000 after a reboot).

Yes I know (now) you shouldn't use `Identity` for this. So I thought the solution would be using a `Sequence`.

I did this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SeqInvoice
AS INTEGER
START WITH 2971
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 999999999
NO CYCLE;
```

And to get next number do this.

```
 SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SeqInvoice;
```

worked fine ..... until I noticed a gap - it jumped from 3028 to 3067

I thought `Sequence` was supposed to not have gaps.

Can `Sequence` have gaps?

If so do I need to have table with last number used and use transactions to ensure no duplicates?

Comment: The gaps are documented and expected.  Learn to love'm.

Comment: Gordon - I know there are  gaps in Identity - I didn't think they were in Sequence - if so whats the point of Sequence - it's broken if it can have gaps

Comment: It isn't broken. It is because of caching. As already stated this is well documented. Read the section about cache here carefully. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql

Comment: so what method do you guys use to get a unique sequential number for say invoices?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column

Comment: I don't need to worry about things like gaps in invoice numbers. You could possibly use ROW_NUMBER or something to generate new numbers.

Comment: Sean - auditors do not like gaps in invoice numbers

My requirement is to have a unique sequential number with no gaps.

row_number won't cut it.

If i do a max on invoicenumber - I think 2 users could potentially at the same time get the same number.

ok it might be rare but still possible

so has anyone got a solution?

do I need transactions? will that help?

Comment: I have never known an auditor that worried about gaps in invoice numbers. Are you saying you can't delete an invoice? Some systems don't allow that but others do, at least until the status changes from "created" (or whatever) to some other status like mailed, paid etc..

Comment: This is kind of a pain to deal with in sql server and there is no easy way that I know of to 100% ensure no gaps and not create a race condition like you described.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the logic of the situation for a minute. In the case that you came up with - two users creating invoices at the same time - how do you handle it if one user gets the "next" invoice number, then they change their mind and cancel it. Or the system crashes. Or they lose their connection. These are just some of the reasons that there isn't a built in "no gaps" type of ID. SQL Server needs to be able to have ACID transactions and that can't be done with autoincrementing numbers that never have gaps.

The best solution that I can come up with is to have your system generate an invoice number as soon as someone starts to create an invoice. That's *immediately* saved to the database. If anything happens to that invoice (the user cancels it, the system crashes, etc.) then the invoice is canceled out in the system by giving it a canceled status code or something along those lines. That way it will still exist and you can point to it for the auditors and say, "Here's why that invoice number doesn't have a real invoice attached - the user created it, but then canceled it." (for example)

To generate the invoice number you could use a single table with a single column and single row for `next_invoice_number`. When your system wants to generate a new invoice number it locks that table, saves a blank invoice in the Invoices table with the next number, increments the `next_invoice_number` in the table, then releases the lock on the table. If you have a lot of users creating invoices then this could cause problems with users having to wait for the locks on the table to be released, but it's about the best that you can do, IMO.

Comment: Yeah that pretty much describes the steps needed to pull this off.

Comment: in my system what actually happens is the invoice is inserted into sql. then immediately the invoice number is generated and the row updated.

The invoice number is actually a string built up from a letter to determine the system plus an incremental number, so P002345, P002346 etc

I used to created it from it ID - but since moving to later SQL we get gaps.

I then tried to use a sequence thinking no gaps.

Again we get gaps.

Answer (score 1):

A `SEQUENCE` in SQL Server caches a default of 50 sequential values in memory, so when a reboot or power outage etc. occurs, yes, there can be gaps of up to 50 numbers.

**BUT:** the `CREATE SEQUENCE` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) does allow you to **specify** how many cached sequential numbers you want - with the `CACHE n` directive. You can also use `NO CACHE` to have absolutely no caching - then, you should pretty much avoid gaps altogether - **BUT** at the price that dishing out the sequential numbers with `NEXT VALUE FOR ...` becomes a bit slower. Take your pick!